# Common Dialog box in all Activities

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialog

I want to put a network check for all Activities, so that if no network is available, a Dialog box will appear and has to finish the current Activity.

For that I created a ConnectionDetector file to check the connection.
In this java file  I created a Dialog box.
When I click the Dialog box Button, the calling Activity has to be finished.

How to send current activity as parameter?

My Activity

```
if (!ConnectionDetector.isConnectingToInternet()) {
       ConnectionDetector.noConnectionDialog(getApplicationContext(), this);
}
```

ConnectionDetector.java

```
public class ConnectionDetector {

    private Context _context;

    public ConnectionDetector(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
    }

    public static boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) AppController.getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        return true;
                    }

        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void noConnectionDialog(final Context context, final Activity activity) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        dialog.setTitle("Network error");
        dialog.setMessage("There seems to be a connection problem. Please check your network connection and try again");
        dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                activity.finish();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

It is getting null pointer exception , activity is not getting finished.

Comment: You can create a default activity and extends all activities from your new activity.

Comment: i accept ur answer, but i want any other way, because its take lot of time

Comment: As I see you already passing the activity as parameter what is the problem?

Comment: it is getting null pointer exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using custom activity we can achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are always going to use show this dialog form activity you can also do

```
public static void noConnectionDialog(final Context context) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        dialog.setTitle("Network error");
        dialog.setMessage("There seems to be a connection problem. Please check your network connection and try again");
        dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                
                 dialog.dismiss();
                 ((Activity)context).finish();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void noConnectionDialog(final Context context, String c) {

        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.nointernet);
        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        ImageButton close;
        close = dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        if (c.equals("1")) {
            dialog.show();
        } else {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```